# How can I have multiple instance of same Javascript Module?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have the following module

```
var TestModule = (function () {
var myTestIndex;

var module = function(testIndex) {
    myTestIndex = testIndex;
    alertMyIndex();
};

module.prototype = {
    constructor: module,
    alertMyIndex: function () {
        alertMyIndex();
    }
};

function alertMyIndex() {
    alert(myTestIndex);
}

return module;
}());
```

And I declare 3 instances of it

```
var test1 =  new TestModule(1);
var test2 = new TestModule(2);
var test3 = new TestModule(3);
```

How do i get

```
test1.alertMyIndex();
```

to show 1 instead of 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign it as a property of `this` instead of a local variable.

```
var module = function(testIndex) {
    this.myTestIndex = testIndex;
    alertMyIndex();
};
```

Then refer to it with `this` within `prototype` methods.